# KMM: Can't reference shared module commonMain source set classes from another module

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I have included a shared model to reference in the module, but I can't seem to import it

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.20"
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.8.20"
    id("io.quarkus")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

val quarkusPlatformGroupId: String by project
val quarkusPlatformArtifactId: String by project
val quarkusPlatformVersion: String by project

dependencies {
    //removing configuration = configurations.default.name causes errors that's why it's there
    implementation(project(path = ":shared", configuration = configurations.default.name)) 
    //...other deps
}

//..other
```

It offers to add the same dependancy I have already added.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can make this module multiplatform with a single jvm platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to add a backendMain folder and jvm("backend") in the build.grade to the shared module